# Using IBM Cloud for SaaS API management with on premise gateways

Tags: ibm-datapower, apiconnect, secure-gateway, hybrid-cloud, onpremises-gateway

Been going through documentation and threads on different fora the last days. (will ask our local IBM expert, but he is quite busy these days).. So turning to you wonderful people :-)

Part of implementing our new cloud strategy we want to move as much as possible to the cloud (as many others do), but it will take some time.

During that migration period, we will have a lot of internal applications using internal API's. But we would love to have our API management solution running in the cloud as SaaS - for many reasons not needing to be discussed here, he he.

So the question is - is it all possible to have our API management in the IBM cloud, but spinning up secure gateways (datapower instances) on premise, connecting to the API management solution in the cloud, pulling down the configuration and run as they do "today", where we have the IBM API connect on premise as well.

We would not want our internal applications to use the gateways in the cloud, the latency would not be acceptable for us at the moment.

Hope a quick "yes" or "no" can be found here - so we can look in the right direction.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Yes - You can connect to Gateways on-premise, while having the rest of the API Connect components (Portal, Manager, Analytics) running on our cloud and managed by us. - The offering is referred to as `API Connect Reserved Instance`, where you get your own reserved single-tenant API Connect.